# Are two objects equivalent in a category when their hom sets are isomorphic?

Tags: category-theory

For instance, if, for all $a$ in a category $C$, $\hom(a, b)$ is equal to $\hom(a, c)$ when all instances of $c$ are replaced by $b$ in the latter, does this imply equivalence of $b$ and $c$ in $C$? If so, is this a necessary condition for equivalence of objects in $C$?

Comment: What do you mean by equivalence? Are you talking about equality/being isomorphic? Also what do you mean by equal Hom classes? Do you also mean isomorphic here?

Comment: @mrtaurho I think so, though I do not see why there is no isomorphism between $x_0$ and $x_1$ in that counterexample. Ad described, it seems like there is nothing to distinguish $x_0$ from $x_1$.

Comment: @ThorWittich, I was thinking isomorphic in both cases.

Comment: @mrtaurho Hmm, I think I see the issue (maybe): we can't say anything about $x_0$ and $x_1$'s structure internally, as category theory has absracted that away. $x_0$ could be an elephant and $x_1$ could be the number $7$, and it'd still work. But it seems like the notion of hom-set equivalence as shown in that example must convey some important notion of equivalence for the objects within the Category, at least (assuming I haven't missed something else, which is quite likely).

Comment: If you ask that the isomorphism of the homsets be a *natural* isomorphism (regarding $\operatorname{Hom}(-,b)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(-,c)$ as functors), then this is the (co)Yoneda lemma. Otherwise, no.